# Using turtle import to print shapes diagonally

Tags: python, python-turtle

So far I have

draw the shape of triangles across the page of increasing size

```
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4

for shapes in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
#draw a triangle
for side in range(1, 4):
    forward(30 + shapes * 10)
    left(120)

move forward to start position of next triangle
penup()
forward(40 + shapes *10)
pendown()
```

but I can't figure out how to print them in a straight diagonal line upwards to achieve > [the aim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDO7g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a rotation to go in the right direction at the beginning. Then draw the triangle to the right instead of the left and you have it.

```py
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4

left(60) # Added
for shapes in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    for side in range(1, 4):
        forward(30 + shapes * 10)
        right(120) # Edited

    # move forward to start position of next triangle
    penup()
    forward(40 + shapes *10)
    pendown()
```